cannot download repository.txt after clicking on mingw-w64-install.exe
after downloading from sourceforge. when I click on that exe file it say's  getting repository description file . after a moment it showed cannot download repository.txt. can someone solve this issue?
I expected a smooth installation

You shouldn't be downloading anything from sourceforge for VSCode, the compiler install or libraries. My advice is to follow the official VSCode instructions and install msys2 and use that to install MinGW. The official instructions are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Recommendation: Stop trying to shoot yourself in the foot and follow the installation instructions. Yeah. What he ^ said!

I don't know where exactly you downloaded this installer, but know that there are quite some old downloads of older GCC+MinGW-w64 versions.
You can get a recent standalone version for Windows without installer from https://winlibs.com/.
Or more advanced command line users may choose to install MSYS2 shell and install MinGW-w64 via its package manager (pacman).
